# Parsing json data from python for apexcharts JS

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, apexcharts

I'm trying to pass **python** lists through html to **javascript**, and it works on my dummy data where both values are list of numbers ('[20, 4, 2, 12]', '[5, 7, 6, 0, 0]')

When I run the real values through ('[0, 0, 0]', '["20-12-24 (13:00)", "20-12-24 (14:00)", "20-12-24 (15:00)"]') through it it doesn't work

Dummy value code python:

```
def senddata(name,wordname):

frequency_time_data = []
word__frequency_data = []
timeframe__frequency_data = []

for x in range(len(name)):
    word__frequency_data.append(random.randrange(0, 30, 1))

for x in range(len(wordname)):
    timeframe__frequency_data.append(random.randrange(0, 10, 1))

#frequency_time_data=[word__frequency_data,timeframe__frequency_data]

return json.dumps(word__frequency_data),json.dumps(timeframe__frequency_data)
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden"  id="word_frequency" value="{{ word_frequency | safe }}">
<input type="hidden"  id="time_frequency" value="{{ time_frequency | safe }}">
```

JS Code:

```
var word_frequency = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#word_frequency').value)

var time_frequency = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#time_frequency').value)
```

dummy output that works with js parse:('[20, 4, 2, 12]', '[5, 7, 6, 0, 0]')

real output that doesnt work with js parse(contains list of strings): ('[0, 0, 0]', '["20-12-24 (13:00)", "20-12-24 (14:00)", "20-12-24 (15:00)"]')

Comment: Please present your code as actual text. If we'd like to copy your code we'd have to write it  again from your images. You can make code blocks by opening and closing with three backticks. (```)

Comment: That being said; JS is trying to read the JSON from HTML elements. How is the data represented on those HTML elements? Can you add those elements? Have you considered outputting the JSON data in `<script>` tag as JavaScript or fetching them through AJAX?

Comment: Added Code, Have not tried Ajax, first time doing this so i went with what i thought was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the "| safe" from html